# Convergence criteria for real Riemann zeta function

Tags: convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

It is well known that the following series converges for $x > 1$, where $x$ is real.

$$ \zeta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}$$

Why is this? I have searched and can't find an answer, and most sources read as if it is so obvious it doesn't need an explanation.

For $x=1$ I know this is the divergent harmonic series.

A [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) fails to conclude convergence:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^x}{n^x} = 1$$

I've even plotted a graph of this and observed that as $x$ varies between 0 and 10, the limit still approaches 1.

I'm not mathematically trained so I'd appreciate explanations with minimum technical language.

Comment: Integral test. Have you heard of $p$-series test?

Comment: I agree it's hard to track this down on Wikipedia. It is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#p-series). You either use the integral test (as Clayton suggested) or you can something less well-known but quite interesting called the Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: i've not heard of the p-series test and the cauchy condensaion test sounds like it takes us into the complex domain which I wanted to avoid for the purely real version of this function. I will look at the p-test

Comment: @RobArthan We need neither the integral test nor Cauchy's condensation test.  I've posted a way forward that circumvents both.

Comment: thanks everyone for contributions and also confirming this question isn't as innocent as it seems .. looks like many texts gloss over the explanation

Comment: @MarkViola: what extra insights does your ad hoc proof offer?

Comment: First, it is not "ad hoc" as you assert. Second, it provides a distinct way forward and introduces a methodology that is useful more broadly.  Third, it provides a way forward without knowledge/use of integral calculus.  Fourth, it not only proves convergence, but reveals the pole singularity at $x=1$. Did you wish to ask anything else?

Comment: @MarkViola: I didn't mean to be denigratory by saying "ad hoc" just that it is specific to this series rather than an application of a general method. Thanks for pointing out that it does indeed yield useful information that the general methods do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x}\le1+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^x}\,dt$$

and

$$\int_1^{a}\frac{1}{t^x}\,dt=\left[\frac1{1-x}t^{1-x}\right]_1^{a}=\frac1{1-x}a^{1-x}-\frac1{1-x}$$

thus for $x>1$

$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^x}\,dt=\lim_{a\to \infty}\int_1^{a}\frac{1}{t^x}\,dt=\frac1{x-1}$$

Comment: i like this one becuase it relies on an intuition that beginners like me can understand  .. that A <= B if B is a continuous integral where A is a discretely samples sum

Comment: @MYOAlgorithmicArt You are welocome! It is indeed a standard way. In any case take also into consideration and try to understand the very interesting approches presented in other answers. Bye

Comment: for anyone else who finds this page .. this resource I liked very much too: http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/Courses/107/Series/inttest.htm

Comment: Take also a look here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx

Comment: why is the first inequality $\leq$ and not $<$ ?

Answer (score 4):

> I thought it might be instructive to present an approach that relies on neither the integral test nor the Cauchy condensation test.  Rather we make use of creative telescoping.  To that end we proceed.

---

First we note that for $x>1$

$$\frac{1}{n^x}=\frac{n^{1-x}-(n-1)^{1-x}}{1-x}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{1+x}}\right)\tag1$$

We can show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ by a host of methodologies.  And hence, for any $\epsilon>0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2+\epsilon}}$ converges.

Therefore, summing both sides of $(1)$ and exploiting the telescoping series reveals

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n^x}=1+\frac{1-N^{1-x}}{x-1}+\sum_{n=2}^N O\left(\frac{1}{n^{1+x}}\right)\tag2$$

For $x>1$, the second term on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $\frac1{x-1}$ as $N\to \infty$ while the second term converges faster than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Hence, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}$ converges.

Comment: thanks this a very interesting angle on the question :)

Comment: @MYOAlgorithmicArt You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you think that Cauchy Condensation involves complex analysis.

> > **CC** Suppose $a_n\ge0$ and $a_{n+1}\le a_n$. The series $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if the series $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converges.

No complex numbers in sight.

Now suppose $x>0$ and $a_n=1/n^x$. Then $$2^na_{2^n}=2^{(1-x)n},$$and it's clear that $\sum 2^{(1-x)n}$ converges if and only if $1-x<0$.