# Determine $r\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log (n)^{r}}{n}$ is converegent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have tried using the Cauchy condensation test.

Here is the statement of the test from my textbook: **Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a monotonic decreasing sequence of numbers. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ if convergent iff. $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{k} a_{2^{k}}$**.

So in my case i have:

$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log (n)^{r}}{n}
$$

My first problem is that the series i'm investigating does not start from $n=1$ as in the theorem but $n=2$. I do not know how to tackle this so I have moved forward and instead of started from $k=0$ is have started from $k=1$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^ka_{2^k}=\log{(2)^r}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^r
$$

Is what I have done so far correct or not?
If yes, have should I proceed from here?

Kind regards,

Btw: instead of downvoting my question tell me what's wrong about it.

Comment: Yes the solution is to find for which $r$ the series $\log{(2)^r}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^r$ **converges**, and before that the essential step is to show that $\frac{\log(n)^r}{n}$ is **decreasing non-negative** for $n$ large enough. The convergence doesn't depend on the first few terms that's why we don't care of if it starts at $n=1$.

Comment: Alright. $\log (2)^{r} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{r}$ is convergent iff. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{r}$. So this is the series I need to investigate. If I assume this series is convergent then the sequence $\{k^r\}_{k \in\mathbb{N}}$ should have limit $0$. Right? Just by looking I can see this is the case for $r \leq -1$. But now I have to prove this claim. This is where I run out of ideas :-). Please help.

Comment: $r$ has to be strictly smaller than $-1$, for $r=-1$, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^r$ is the harmonic series, which is divergent!

Comment: @R.J.Etienne
Oh, yeah! So I can say for $r = -1$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{r} is theharmonic series and therefore not convergent. If mention this. Then my claim $r< -1 $ holds. But again:  have to prove this, which is hard.

Comment: In a nutshell: your question is in fact related to an expression for the Riemann Zeta function: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^r=\zeta(-r)$, which converges for $r<-1$

Comment: @R.J.Etienne 
We have only very basic knowledge about series available. So I can't use the Riemann Zeta funciton.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812654/convergence-criteria-for-real-riemann-zeta-function , you could probably use one of the proofs there

Comment: I have. I do not think I can use it. But I will think about it again. Thanks.

Comment: @Xenusi There is not much to prove.  The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^r$ converges for $r<-1$ and diverges otherwise.  You can appeal to the $p-test$, the integral test, etc.

Comment: @MarkViola

Using the integral test I get 

$$ 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}+ \frac{1}{r+1}
$$

"The integral diverges for $r <-1$." I do not know if that is sufficient.
 The case $r = -1$ I can consider separately. 

But actually then I could just use the integral test on the original series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log (n)^{r}}{n}$, right? Then there is no point in using the Cauchy condensation test?

Thanks.

Comment: The integral test shows convergence for $r<-1$.  $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{r+1}=0$ for $r<-1$.

Comment: @MarkViola

I can see that. But then I could just apply the integral test directly on $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\log (n)^{r}}{n}$, right?

Comment: @Xenusi Yes, you could apply the integral test to the original series.  If you don't like the integral test, use the p-test.

Comment: @MarkViola
Oh, I forgot one thing. To use the integral test I have to start from $n=1$, my series starts from $n=2$. How can I fix this? By saying: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log (n)^{r}}{n} - \frac{\log (1)^{r}}{1}$. The last term is $0$. Right?

Comment: The lower limit really doesn't matter since you are testing series convergence.  That is, you may start the series from any fixed integer $N\ge 1$ since the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n$ is obviously finite.  You do need to make sure that $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks!

Comment: Note that a second application of the condensation test will work here.

Comment: @MarkViola 
What do you mean? work on what?

Comment: I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We begin with the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log^r(n)}{n}$ and are asked to find the values of $r$ for which the series converges.

Applying the Cauchy Condensation test to the series reveals that the original series converges if and only if the series $\displaystyle \log^r(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^r$ converges.

Next, we apply the Cauchy Condensation test once more to the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^r$.  That series converges if and only if we have convergence of the condensed series
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}2^n (2^n)^r&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(2^{r+1}\right)^n\tag1
\end{align}$$

The series on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is a geometric series, which converges if and only if $2^{r+1}<1$.  And $2^{r+1}<1$ if and only if $r<-1$.  So, our original series converges if $r< -1$ and diverges otherwise.

And we are done!

Comment: Why from $n=1$ in $\log ^{r}(2) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{r}$ and from $n=0$ in $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(2^{r+1}\right)^{n}$?

Comment: Also, I do not think you should use the same index for all the series you have mentioed.

Comment: @Xenusi First, look at the theorem as you wrote it.  Next, the summation index is a "dummy" and so we need not be concerned with which symbol we choose.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.