# question about logic of integral comparison tests

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

A common way of determining that the Riemann zeta function $\sum \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges for $s>1$ is to undertake an integral comparison test.

The following are two examples of this approach:

- [Convergence criteria for real Riemann zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812654/convergence-criteria-for-real-riemann-zeta-function).
- https://fromprimestoriemann.blogspot.com/2021/02/integral-comparison-tests.html

A key step in the logic is to establish the following inequality, based on the fact that the "area" of the discrete partial sums is less than the area under the related curve:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n^s} -1 < \int_1^{k}\frac{1}{x^s}\,dx$$

The usual strategy is to find for which $s$ the integral converges as $k \rightarrow \infty$, and then say that the discrete sum also converges for the same condition on $s$, because the sum is always less than the integral.

My **question** is one about the logic of this strategy:

- the integral converges for $s>1$
- the discrete sum is always less than integral
- so surely the convergence range for  the discrete sum can be larger than for the integral?

To expand on this argument - because the sum is always less than the integral, it could be made "larger" by a small amount, and still remain less than the integral. This small enlargement could be done by, $s=0.999" for example.

**Where is the flaw in my thinking?**

(I am not a university trained mathematician and would welcome replies with minimal technical terminology).

Comment: There is an easy inequality  the other way  where you take the integral from $2$ to $k+1$ using that now $1/n^k \ge1/x^k, n \le x \le n+1$ so the convergence range of the series is now greater or equal to that of the second  integral. But the latter is same as the first integral since they differ only at the start point ($1$ vs $2$) so indeed the series has same convergence same the integral; this is a general result for all monotonic functions (when decreasing generally used for convergence  range, when increasing used for asymptotic estimates)

Comment: @Conrad - does this mean that a complete proof needs to demonstrate both inequalities, above and below?

Comment: Yes if you want to show that the convergence  range is same; if you want to show that $\zeta$ converges when the integral does, only what is in the op is enough but I agree that doesn't  imply that zeta cannot converge for a larger range - of course it doesn't but that requires the extra step mentioned

Comment: @Conrad that sounds like an answer to me. I'll happily mark it as such if you added it.

Comment: @Conrad can ask why the inequality between the discrete sum and the continuous integral is  $\leq \geq$ and not <> ? The usual visualisation using rectangles plotted against the curve shows under/over estimates with no possibility of equality.

Comment: Yes it can be strict if you wish but that is unimportant here

Comment: @Conrad I've updated my "blog writeup" with new logic. We use the strict <and > inequalities, and show that (1) the integral and therefore sum converges when s>1, and (2) the integral and therefore sum diverges when s<=1. is it just me or are most texts/sources a little loose on the inequalities?

Comment: depends on context - sometimes it is unimportant if an inequality is strict or even one needs only a $<<$ (eg for absolute convergence purposes, $<<$  is enough), sometimes it is important especially if one needs the cases when the inequality becomes equality or whether inequality can be improved or that is not possibble (in latter case inequality is called sharp)